# NameError: name " " is not defined (new to coding cand figure out why it doesn't work)

Tags: python

So I have this [file](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/6/scourgify/before.csv). So my understanding is that DictReader reads the csv file creating a dictionary for each line. The I create the first and last name by calling on name"key" and first, last and house goes again into a dictionary that is appended to the students list. Please let me know if any of the steps I am describing are wrong or why I am getting the error below. Thank you!

```
import csv

students =[]
with open("before.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        first,last = row["name"].strip().split(',')
        house = row["house"]
        students.append({"first":first, "last":last, "house":row["house"]})
    print (students)
```

```
$ python before.csv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/115945517/before.csv", line 1, in <module>
    name,house
    ^^^^
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```bash
python before.csv
```

you're telling python to execute the csv file as a python script. A csv file is just a way of storing data, "comma separated values".

You need to run

```bash
python your_script.py
```

where `your_script` is the name of the python file (`.py`) that you're working on.

Comment: I feel stupid to say the least. Thank you so much for point this out!